# how to convert normal time in Julian time sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, julian-date

I have tried below code to convert the normal date to Julian date but now I want to convert `HH:MM:SS` to Julian time

converting a Julian date

```
SELECT DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()) * 1000 + DATEPART(dy, GETDATE())
```

сonverts back to a regular date

```
SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, CAST(RIGHT('13000', 3) AS INT) - 1, CAST(CONCAT('', LEFT('13000', 4)) AS time)) AS in_date
```

Comment: Your calculation for Julian date doesn't look correct anyway. Today is 22223 not 2022223

Comment: @MartinSmith I think it depends on the date format,  `2022223` in `YYYYJJJ`, `22223` in `YYJJJ`

Comment: Sample input/output would be a really good idea. The term "Julian time" is quite broad and refers to many [variants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day#Variants) on a theme.

Comment: All are related to some notion of ordinals, but that still leaves a lot of wiggle room. For example, `DATETIME` itself is ordinal-based, and `CONVERT(FLOAT, GETDATE())` will give you a kind of "Julian time" starting from 1900-01-01 (not that I'm suggesting you should be using this -- it's not very clear and doesn't work for the newer `DATE`, `TIME` and `DATETIME2` types).